# Using Rolle's theorem to find the number of real roots

Tags: calculus

Prove using Rolle’s theorem that not all zeroes of the polynomial

> $$p(x) = x^4 - \sqrt 7 x^3 + 4x^2 - \sqrt {22}x + 15$$

are real.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please add what you've tried, and/or how you think Rolle's Theorem can be used, and/or clarify what you don't understand. We encourage that when posting a homework question, a user provides some context for the problem, his/her thoughts or attempts to solve the question or prove a proposition. At the very least, try to provide definitions, applicable theorems along with how you think they might help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $p''(x)=12x^2-6\sqrt7x+8$ has no real roots.